# Ubuntu 16.04 stuck in login from Parallels desktop access

Tags: 16.04, login, parallels

I know a similar question has been asked before, but the proposed solutions do not work for me as I am accessing Ubuntu from my Mac by means of Parallels Desktop.
The login worked fine until a couple of days ago but now, when I type in my password the screen goes black and shortly after returns to the login page. How can I fix this from my Parallels access from my Mac, without losing the files stored?
Thank you for your help, it is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried dropping into shell by using ctrl+alt+f3 and then logging in. You can always go back by using ctrl+alt+f1

After you login you might want to check if there is a config issue with your particular user by adding a new one and testing login:

```
sudo adduser testuser
sudo systemctl reboot
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work because i am accessing it from my Mac, so using ctrl+alt+f3 doesn't really lead anywhere. Also, I have the same problem when I try to access as Guest User

Comment: I am running it on VM on my Mac. Not too sure about parallels but have you tried disabling graphics acceleration in settings for parallels?